# Neither Anaconda Navigator or Jupyter Notebook will open

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I recently installed Anaconda on my Mac (running OS X 10.8.5), and I'm having several errors:

(1) When I try to open the Anaconda Navigator from the anaconda3 folder, the icon displays on my Dock then quickly disappears.

(2) When I use the command `anaconda-navigator` in terminal, it displays this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 172, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

(3) When I use the command `jupyter notebook` in terminal, it displays this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 45, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _memset_s
  Referenced from: /Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/libsodium.23.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/jakesansom/anaconda3/lib/libsodium.23.dylib
```

I'm not sure if these issues are related or not, but I decided to post all of them just in case.

Comment: This is Satan's work. The only way to beat him is by try reinstalling.

Comment: i would also recommend going to jupyter or anacaonda's github to resolve installation issues. Google the errors and go issue pages on git.

Comment: Haha yes I agree. I've tried reinstalling Anaconda, installing Miniconda instead, uninstalling and reinstalling pyzmq and pyqt using conda install, and a couple other things. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/520

Comment: Well, I tried doing this too, and it didn't work. Same error code coming up.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue attempting to use paramiko under OS X 10.6.8. ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _memset_s. Where did you get your python from? Perhaps Python should have been built with "-no_weak_imports linker flag" see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/3727